# Encountering Deployment Issue to Heroku

Tags: heroku, error-handling, deployment

i dont know why, im getting this error:

```
2023-08-02T22:04:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-08-02T22:05:03.277361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2023-08-02T22:05:04.879593+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
2023-08-02T22:05:05.045132+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-08-02T22:05:05.045133+00:00 app[web.1]: > flexflix@1.0.0 start
2023-08-02T22:05:05.045134+00:00 app[web.1]: > node dist/server.js
2023-08-02T22:05:05.045134+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094904+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094908+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094908+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094909+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094909+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/server.js'
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094909+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._resolveFilename 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094910+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._load 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094910+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as 
runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094911+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094911+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094912+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: []
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094912+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094912+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-08-02T22:05:05.094912+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.17.0
2023-08-02T22:05:05.258509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-08-02T22:05:05.293109+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-08-02T22:05:06.380890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
method=GET path="/" host=flexflix-caa1faedaa40.herokuapp.com request_id=4fc1c954-e6ff-448f- 
8f11-3b6fb58788ee fwd="46.121.142.35" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-08-02T22:05:07.292613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=flexflix-caa1faedaa40.herokuapp.com request_id=0d9f9bd9- 
faee-4743-8819-8b24049c17bf fwd="46.121.142.35" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=https
```

as you can see, the build succeeded but the app crashed.
i dont know what this module is and where i can find it:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/server.js'
```

you can see im trying to do node dist/server.js but it adds app/ at the beggining i don't know why.

anyone have a solution for me?
thanks.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?